# Pantheios in Qt creator with VS C++ 2008 compiler

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008, qt-creator, pantheios

I can't compile my project that uses **Pantheios** (version 1.0.1-beta210) logger in **Qt Creator** (creator 2.5.2 + SDK 4.8.2 compiled from sources with VS2008 compiler) with **VS2008 C++ compiler**.
But it works with Visual Studio 2008!

1. First, I've compiled Pantheios library as it should be using VS command line and nmake with path `pantheios_path\build\vc9\`
2. Then I have written a simple Qt program using VS2008 with Qt Addin and it works fine:

   ```
   #include <pantheios/pantheios.hpp>
   #include <pantheios/inserters/args.hpp>
   #include <pantheios/backends/bec.WindowsConsole.h>

   #include <pantheios/implicit_link/core.h>
   #include <pantheios/implicit_link/fe.simple.h>
   #include <pantheios/implicit_link/be.WindowsConsole.h>

   #include <QApplication>
   #include "MainWindow.h"

   extern "C" const char PANTHEIOS_FE_PROCESS_IDENTITY[] = PANTHEIOS_LITERAL_STRING("play.with.logger");

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       QApplication a(argc, argv);
       MainWindow w;
       w.show();

       pantheios::log(pantheios::debug, "debug processing condition");

       return a.exec();
   }
   ```
3. But when I export it to Qt Creator project it doesn't want to link with errors:

   ```
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegCloseKey@4 referenced in function _pantheios_util_onBailOut_canUseWarnMessage_x_
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.time.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegCloseKey@4
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegQueryValueExA@24 referenced in function _pantheios_util_onBailOut_canUseWarnMessage_x_
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.time.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegQueryValueExA@24
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegOpenKeyA@12 referenced in function _pantheios_util_onBailOut_canUseWarnMessage_x_
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.time.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegOpenKeyA@12
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DeregisterEventSource@4 referenced in function _pantheios_onBailOut3
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ReportEventA@36 referenced in function _pantheios_onBailOut3
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegisterEventSourceA@8 referenced in function _pantheios_onBailOut3
   debug\Logging3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
   ```

   By the way, in `project.pro` file I set:

   ```
   ...
       INCLUDEPATH += $(STLSOFT)/include \
                  $(PANTHEIOS_ROOT)/include

       LIBS += -L$(PANTHEIOS_ROOT)/lib
   ...
   ```
4. Also I have tryed to change LIBS variable following way:

   ```
   LIBS += d:\workspaces\VS\pantheios-1.0.1-beta210_32\lib\pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib \
       d:\workspaces\VS\pantheios-1.0.1-beta210_32\lib\pantheios.1.core.vc9.dll.debug.lib \
       d:\workspaces\VS\pantheios-1.0.1-beta210_32\lib\pantheios.1.fe.simple.vc9.dll.debug.lib \
       d:\workspaces\VS\pantheios-1.0.1-beta210_32\lib\pantheios.1.bec.WindowsConsole.vc9.dll.debug.lib \
       d:\workspaces\VS\pantheios-1.0.1-beta210_32\lib\pantheios.1.be.WindowsConsole.vc9.dll.debug.lib
   ```

   And get this:

   ```
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegCloseKey@4 referenced in function _pantheios_util_onBailOut_canUseWarnMessage_x_
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.time.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegCloseKey@4
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegQueryValueExA@24 referenced in function _pantheios_util_onBailOut_canUseWarnMessage_x_
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.time.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegQueryValueExA@24
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegOpenKeyA@12 referenced in function _pantheios_util_onBailOut_canUseWarnMessage_x_
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.time.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegOpenKeyA@12
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DeregisterEventSource@4 referenced in function _pantheios_onBailOut3
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ReportEventA@36 referenced in function _pantheios_onBailOut3
   pantheios.1.util.vc9.dll.debug.lib(util.bailout.dll.debug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegisterEventSourceA@8 referenced in function _pantheios_onBailOut3
   debug\Logging3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
   ```

I also tried different combinations of :

```
LIBS += -L$(PANTHEIOS_ROOT)/lib -llibname_without_extension
```

Can anyone give me a helpful advice? Maybe someone use Pantheios under Qt Creator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please search the functions in MSDN, then you can get what libraries you missed. For example, to the symbol "_*imp*_RegCloseKey@4”, please search “RegCloseKey” in MSDN, you can find that you missed “Advapi32.lib”. Then you shall add this library in your `.pro` file.

```
LIBS += -lAdvapi32
```